# common Url for all the apps in django

Tags: django, url

**I want your help, I am new in Django**

suppose I have 2 apps name  1. school
2. college

1. The school app has its separate url.py and view.py file. If I want to show contact-us page, then I have to crate URL be like

   localhost://school/contact-us
   and there is separate view.py file in school app for handling view for **"/contact-us"** url

2, Now in **college app** there is also contact-us page and both school and college have the same contact us page.  I don't want to write the same code again for the college app. It's increasing my code as well a time to develop a project, I am writing whole project HTML pages urls in every app.

may I have more apps like medical college, etc

so, is there any way to get this done. can you tell me have to write a single URL and view for the common page?

Comment: Just build a single app for `contact us` and then you can implement and call it wherever and whenever needed

Comment: I cant build an app for every HTML page in the project